# Angular [routerLink] does not work when part of HTML imported from database

Tags: angular

I sort of understand why the following does not work but perhaps I can get some guidance or some workaround?

So I am using a module that builds tree structure from an array that I import from a webApi. I do not have much control over the node name (that is what is displayed on every level of the tree) via Angular but I can control the HTML of the node name using [innerHTML]="node.data.name | safeHtml" All is well and good and if I click on inspect element of a node I see the following

```html
<a [routerlink]="/account-detail/a7e9f9ba-e202-4122-8275-4010b47ffc55">Account 1</a>
```

The problem is that clicking on the link does not work. I did test this exact same HTML by pasting it above the tree view directly in the Angular HTML template and it works fine then. My guess is that because I import this HTML that there is no binding between the dom and Angular script. Unfortunately I am not sure and I have no idea what to search for on Google. I also tried like (click) command but exactly same issue. No errors also in the console.

Any advice would be highly appreciated. I must also just add that if I use a normal href method it works but of course that is a complete page refresh.

Comment: Can you try with [routerLink]="['yourLink']"

Comment: why dont you use `(click)` event? like `<a (click)="coolfunction()"></a>`

Comment: Hi, as much as I was hoping this will work still exactly same interaction. Basically no error but nothing happens. Thanks anyway

Comment: I used [routerLink] as example. Also tried (click) but exactly same issue. Even though the HTML looks 100% correct if you view it using element inspector clicking simply does not do anything. Nothing in the console. Junaid Malik seems to found a way to do it. I am going to try that next. Still trying to understand why that would before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

in angularjs it could be achieved using $compile directive, but this $compile directive has been dropped on newer versions. i faced this issue some days ago. there is a npm module that can be used to achieve this. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717287/compile-alternate-in-angular-9) is the link to my question, you can find the solution in answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will respond if this works, will try and implement tonight but I agree it is exactly the same issue

Comment: sure, do let me know if you need any help